# Remove duplicate items in List<T> using .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

While I was trying to remove duplicate items from List using .NET 2.0, I could not get the expected result.

```
    List<Student> list1 = new List<Student>();

    Student s = new Student();
    s.Age = "35";
    s.Name = "Nazmul";
    list1.Add(s);

    s = new Student();
    s.Age = "35";
    s.Name = "Nazmul";
    list1.Add(s);

    s = new Student();
    s.Age = "35";
    s.Name = "Nazmul";
    list1.Add(s);

    s = new Student();
    s.Age = "35";
    s.Name = "Nazmul";
    list1.Add(s);

    IComparer<Student> compare = new MyOrderingClass();

    list1.Sort(compare);
    Int32 index = 0;

    while (index < list1.Count - 1)
    {

        if (list1[index].Equals(list1[index + 1]))
        {
            list1.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        else
        {
            index++;
        }
    }

    foreach (Student st in list1)
    {

        Response.Write("Name:" + st.Name);
        Response.Write("Age:" + st.Age + "<br/>");
    }
```

The class and method used above are listed below:

```
public class Student
{
    private String name;
    private String age;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public String Age { 
        get { return age; } 
        set { age = value; } 
    }
}

public class MyOrderingClass : IComparer<Student>
{
    public int Compare(Student x, Student y)
    {
        int compareName = x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
        if (compareName == 0)
        {
            return x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age);
        }
        return compareName;
    }
}
```

I am getting all the list item as output. Wondering where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor, does .Net 2.0 support Distinct?

Comment: First of all NEVER change a List (IEnumerable) when you are iterating through it.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I think Distinct is a Linq feature introduced in .NET 3.0

Comment: if (list1[index].Equals(list1[index + 1])) never return true, you need override Student.Equals with your values

Comment: @Mate,I have checked and it never returns true. Wondering why?

Comment: @pmtamal, I have used IComparere for sort.

Comment: Default equals only supports reference equality.this may be useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @pmtamal, thank you so much for the reference. What is this method:  "public override int GetHashCode()"

Comment: @Mate, trying with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 2.0 you can use `Dictionary<>` class to get distinct values. Probably it will be most efficient approach using out of box functionality. Obviously in .NET 3.5 and higher use `Distinct` extension method. Here I added .NET 2.0 implementation.

```
public class Student : IEquatable<Student>
{
    private String name;
    private String age;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public String Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + ((Age == null) ? 0 : Age.GetHashCode());
            hash = hash * 23 + ((Name == null) ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode());

            return hash;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(Student other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Age == other.Age && Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
         if (obj == null) return false;
         if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Student)) return false;

         return Equals((Student)obj);
    }
}
```

---

```
Dictionary<Student, bool> dict = new Dictionary<Student, bool>();

foreach (Student student in list1)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(student))
    {
        dict.Add(student, false);
    }
}

ICollection<Student> distinctList = dict.Keys;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What is the purpose of GetHashCode()?

Comment: @Hoque, See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk - you didn't override `Object.Equals` in this example.

Comment: @codekaizen, In this particular case `object.Equals` won't be called.

Comment: @Hoque - while true in this case, it would be defensive to put it in. Leaving 2 different implementations of equality in a single class is very poor design.

Comment: @codekaizen, What do you mean? Implementations are completely the same.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk - try this: 
    `Object s1 = new Student { Name = "abc", Age = "21" };
    Object s2 = new Student { Name = "abc", Age = "21" };
    
    Assert.True(s1.Equals(s2));`

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk - That's what I told _you_ to do! You're missing it and as such the class is poorly designed.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk - perhaps, but chances are this code is going to make it into production somewhere, and as such, I'm trying to help the copy-paster who ends up using it.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk, would you mind to tell me "how do I override object.Equals here"?

Comment: Why do hash = 17 ,and hash = hash * 23 + ((Age == null) ? 0 : Age.GetHashCode());
What about another number, 50, 100,...ect

Answer (score 2):

The core idea you are looking at can be described with an operation - equality - and a data structure - the set.

First, the operation.

Your class `MyOrderingClass` is close to being what you want here. Instead of `IComparer<Student>`, you could use `IEqualityComparer<Student>` which provides a way to determine if two instances are equal. There are two methods which are needed to determine this: `Equals`, of course, and `GetHashCode` which is a sort of "shortcut" method used by some data structures to see if instances are *possibly* equal. The important thing to note here is that the implementation of `GetHashCode` involves the same values which are used in determining equality.

```
public class MyOrderingClass : IEqualityComparer<Student>, IComparer<Student>
{   
    public int Compare(Student x, Student y)   
    {   
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("x");
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("y");
        }

        // Optional: use StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.CompareTo or maybe others 
        // from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx
        int compareName = x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);

        if (compareName == 0)   
        {   
            return x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age);   
        }   

        return compareName;   
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Student student)
    {
        if(student == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("student");
        }

        unchecked
        {
            return (student.Name ?? String.Empty).GetHashCode() ^ student.Age;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
    {
        return Compare(x, y) == 0;
    }
}
```

Second, the data structure.

The idea of having a collection of distinct objects can be accomplished by using the `Distinct` extension method, but it could be helpful to look at an implementation of `ISet<T>` - `HashSet<T>`. The reason for this is that the concept of "distinct elements" is really a definition of the concept of a set - unique elements which belong together. The `HashSet<T>` uses an instance of an `IEqualityComparer<T>` - by default it uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` which does referential equality. Of course you can supply your own, like your newly enhanced `MyOrderingClass`. It turns out that the `Distinct` method uses a hash-based set to keep track of elements it's already seen and yielded, and to that end it can take an instance of `IEqualityComparer<T>` which it passes to this internal set.

So now that we have examined the fundamental concepts, let's see the code:

```
List<Student> list1 = new List<Student>();

// ... add instances with the same name and age

// option 1: use HashSet<T>
var set = new HashSet<Student>(list1, new MyOrderingClass());
Assert.Equal(1, set.Count);

// option 2: use Distinct
var distinct = list1.Distinct(new MyOrderingClass());
Assert.Equal(1, distinct.Count());

// option 3: when you don't have a proper set (e.g. .Net 2.0)
Dictionary<Student, Object> d = new Dictionary<Student, Object>(new MyOrderingClass());
list1.ForEach(delegate(Student e) { d[e] = null; });
Assert.Equal(1, d.Count);
```

Comment: Are "HashSet" and "Distinct" available in .NET 2.0?

Comment: No. You need to use some other implementation like Iesi `HashedSet` (http://nuget.org/packages/Iesi.Collections) or a `Dictionary<K, V>` where you only use the keys and not the values. The remainder is the same.

Comment: But honestly, and I know you probably don't have a choice, you guys need to get off 2.0!

Comment: I added "option 3" to cover using a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

pmtamal mentioned :  Default equals only supports reference equality.this may be useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.80).aspx

```
       public class Student
            {
                private String name;
                private String age;
                public String Name
                {
                    get { return name; }
                    set { name = value; }
                }
                public String Age
                {
                    get { return age; }
                    set { age = value; }
                }

                public override bool Equals(object obj)
                {
                    Student st = obj as Student;
                    if(st != null ){
                        return (this.name.Trim().ToLower().Equals(st.name.Trim().ToLower()) && this.age == st.age);
                    }
                    return base.Equals(obj);
                }

                public override int GetHashCode()
                {
                   return base.GetHashCode();
                }


            }
```

Comment: your equal does not take into consideration the age of the student,

Comment: Yes, i said before... "with your values". I guess @Hoque will add the conditions you need to say that they are equal. Thank for the observation Ganesh R. :)

Comment: @Mate, is there any requirement to override GetHashCode()

Comment: No really for this code... but has mentioned codekaizen,  GetHashCode which is a sort of "shortcut" method used by some data structures to see if instances are possibly equal.  With another object structure is useful